# OpenIddict: How to update the openid-configuration endpoint uri

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, .net-core, google-cloud-run, openiddict

I am building the authentication server using OpenIddict and Net core 7.0, but when I deploy the server to Google Cloud run service, the endpoints of the authentication server are using HTTP. I want to change it to HTTPS. So how do I do it?

[image]

Comment: Check out https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/issues/1379

Comment: Hi @Zulander, I did it but it is not working :(, I changed the endpoint to HTTPS but it returns a page not found :(

Comment: Did you set the relative or absolute uri when configuring the endpointUris? For example did you set SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("/connect/authorize") or SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("http-://yourauthdomain.com/connect/authorize")?

Comment: Hi @Englund0110 I fixed, we need to use HttpsRedirection and Set Issuer URL. Thanks